# Ambiguous use of subscript error

Tags: ios, swift

I read about this error and I know that it alerts when the compiler does not know what type it needs to return, but this error did not appear earlier and I do not know why it appears today.

This is my code:

```
func animateCounter(from: Int, to: Int) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(duration, target: self, selector: "increaseCounter", userInfo: ["from": from, "to": to], repeats: false)
}

func increaseCounter() {
    let from = timer.userInfo!["from"] as! Int
    let to = timer.userInfo!["to"] as! Int
}
```

I set that my `from` and `to` variables are Integers, so why I get this error?

Comment: You have to cast the `userInfo` to a dictionary before being able to access its contents via subscript.

Comment: it's funny, but it works now. I did not make any changes =/

Answer (score 0):

Cast userInfo to `Optional([String:AnyObject])` first and then cast `userInfo["from"], userInfo["to"]` to `Optional(Int)`

Your will need to unwrap the result by yourself :)

```
func increaseCounter() {
    let userInfo = timer.userInfo as? [String: AnyObject]
    if let dict = userInfo {
        let from = dict["from"] as? Int
        let to = dict["to"] as? Int
    }
}
```